# How to verify whether all dictionary KVP are included in some of other dictionary within list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got one dictionary A (let say containing 3 KVP) and a list of dictionaries with many KVPs. I need to verify if there is some dictionary which is including all KVP from dictionary A.

Dictionary A - 3KVP

List A which includes 3 dictionaries containing 20KVP each.

How to verify condition that there is any dictionary within List A containing all KVP from Dictionary A?

Answer (score 4):

Checking whether any dictionary in your list contains all of the key/value pairs of another dictionary is pretty straightforward with LINQ's `Any` and `All` methods.

Something like the following could do it:

```
var result = list.Any(d => dict.All(x => d.ContainsKey(x.Key) && d[x.Key] == x.Value));
```

This checks if any of the dictionary in the lists have all the keys with the same value as our target dictionary.

You can avoid multiple lookups, as pointed out by @mjwills in the comments, by using Dictionary's TryGetValue method. This would look like the following:

```
var result = list.Any(d => dict.All(x => d.TryGetValue(x.Key, out var val) && val == x.Value));
```

This assumes some values looking something like these:

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> {
    new Dictionary<string,string> {
        {"1","1"},
        {"2","2"},
        {"3","3"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string,string> {
        {"4","4"},
        {"5","5"},
        {"6","6"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string,string> {
        {"7","7"},
        {"8","8"},
        {"9","9"}
    }
};

var dict = 
    new Dictionary<string,string> {
        {"7","7"},
        {"8","8"},
        {"9","9"}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct answer will depend on what type the `Key` and `Value` parts are (if one of them is a `List<T>`, for example, the equals comparison is trickier), but in general, ***assuming that all the keys and values have their `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods implemented correctly***, we can use the `System.Linq` extension methods `Any` and `Except` to get the result.

The `Except` method returns all the items from the first collection (`compareDict`) that aren't in the second collection (a dictionary from the list):

```
bool result = listOfDict.Any(dict => !compareDict.Except(dict).Any());
```

This says, *"return `true` if, when we examine the difference between all the items in our comparison dictionary with each dictionary in the list, there are no remaining items from the comparison dictionary (otherwise return `false`) in at least one comparison"*.

This works because a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` implements `Equals` such that it returns `true` if both the `Key` and the `Value` are equal.

Comment: Wouldn't this use the dictionary as an `IEnumerable` and lose the benefits of a constant-time lookup?